# Logging execution and errors of git-receive-pack on restricted server?

Tags: git, logging, ssh

I have limited ssh access to a restricted Linux server; since the server does not include 'git', I simply copied the executables that I have there, and then I use:

```
git config remote.origin.receivepack "/path/to/my/git-receive-pack"
```

... in my local repo.

I managed to get clone/pull working in this context (from server to local), but I have some permission error when doing the push. So I thought, it would be really nice to have a log here, so I can find out where the error lies (hopefully, at the exact file which is to be created or updated). Unfortunately, `git-receive-pack` doesn't have a command line option for logging; so I tried something like:

```
git config remote.origin.receivepack "/usr/bin/git-receive-pack 2>&1 >> /path/to/my/grec.log"
```

... and it does write something like:

```
008860dbe54430bbbd639307d50621c491a4fd69a822 refs/heads/master report-status delete-refs side-band-64k quiet ofs-delta agent=git/1.9.1
0000
```

... in the log file - but unfortunately then the entire `git push` proces locks and doesn't complete; as far as I could see, that is because [git/receive-pack.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/receive-pack.c) already uses stdout and stderr to (I guess) do something internally.

So can I somehow wrap `git-receive-pack` in a shell script on the server, so that all of its operations are logged in a file - but which also interacts with the rest of the git process properly, and completes in order (and doesn't lock)?

Comment: In response to the close vote "unclear what I'm asking": I'm asking if it is possible (and how) to log the execution of git-receive-pack on a server in a logfile?

Comment: `git-receive-pack` it does not have a logging system, maybe they thought it was unnecessary, although in reality it is. It is possible to observe the execution history through the `git log` command, but this does not ensure the origin of the execution or it does not serve to create hooks to the execution of certain commands.